# Differentiating Related Functions - How do I get from the red circle to the blue circle? (see image)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[Khan Academy math problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZx14.jpg)

I understand everything except how we go from:

$-36 \frac{dx}{dt} = -18 \frac{dx}{dt} + 18$

to:

$-18 \frac{dx}{dt} = 18$

Is there a math rule I am missing here? How does this make any sense?

Comment: You get there by adding $18\frac{dx}{dt}$ to both sides of the equation.

Comment: Thank you I have no idea how I didn't see that

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Maybe consider answering? It may attract people even when it has already been solved

Answer (score 1):

As per a suggestion in the comments, I will submit my comment as an answer if only to clear the question.

The pertinent step is to add $18\frac{dx}{dt}$ to both sides of the equation.

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson Thank you. Correction made.